# Can Google Java Auth Library be used to authenticate Firebase Authentication Tokens

Tags: java, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-platform

The python Google authentication library has a method for authenticating tokens from Firebase authentication. How could the java version of the library be used for the same thing? I looked over the [documentation](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-java) and there doesn't seem to be a method for Firebase, just for Google Cloud.